# Parameter wsjpa.PooledFactory is not serializable

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, java-ee-8

When i run application on websphere server i get warning:

```
Property 'wsjpa.PooledFactory' is not serializable, value won't be set.
```

This happends due to hibernate update from version 5.1.17.Final to version 5.4.33.Final.
In my application i use Java EE 8 and JSF 2.3. Websphere version is 22.0.0.4.

Do i need to change something or is it hibernate problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property 'wsjpa.PooledFactory' is a JPA runtime integration property WebSphere intended for **WSJPA**; a WebSphere extension of the persistence provider **OpenJPA**.

It would appear that **Hibernate** is providing a warning because the value of the property 'wsjpa.PooledFactory' is not a serializable value or String type. Since Hibernate does not use this property, this warning should be able to be safely ignored.

Alternatively, it may be possible to prevent this 'wsjpa.PooledFactory' property from being set by the JPA Runtime in the first place by setting the pool size to 0: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=api-jpa-system-properties

Comment: Should i add following code to my server.xml file?
    <com.ibm.websphere.jpa.entitymanager.poolcapacity>0</com.ibm.websphere.jpa.entitymanager.poolcapacity>

Comment: For Websphere Liberty, you can set as a JVM property in the jvm.options folder (https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/server-configuration-overview.html#jvm-options) or as the 'entityManagerPoolCapacity' element of the JPA configuration (https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/jpa.html)